# Why runs 'pip' as Python 3 module but not as script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I've installed Lubuntu 16.04 LTS that comes with Python 3.5, but with Python 2.7 as default Python interpreter.
Both versions comes without `pip` package intalled.  I only will use the 3.5 version.  So I've installed `pip3` with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then I tried to update the `pip` version (because the Ubuntu repositories have old versions):
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip3
But `pip3` can't locate `pip3` package, and sends me this message:

> Collecting pip3
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement pip3 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for
>   pip3

After that, I tried this other:

```
$ pip3 intall --upgrade pip
```

And it updates from pip 8.1.1 to pip 8.1.2

> pip 8.1.2 from /home/trimax/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python
>   3.5)

If I try this:

```
$ pip -V
```

Doesn't work:

> The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing:  sudo apt-get install python-pip

But if I try this:

```
$ python3 -m pip -V
```

That works:

> pip 8.1.2 from /home/trimax/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python
>   3.5)

The question is **Why runs `pip` as module but not as script?**

Comment: does this work? $ pip3 -v

Comment: Because `pip` has been never aliased to `pip3` on your system. Usually, `pip` refers to pip for Python 2, but that's apparently not installed. You can make your own symlink for `pip` if you want to.

Comment: Actually, there is likely a `pip` executable installed in `/home/trimax/.local/bin/`, but that directory is not on your path. Note that this path implies that you have used `--user` somewhere (in the upgrade?), but I don't see that mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 3):

pip3 is in reality the pip package for python3. Since both python2 and python3 can coexist, the pip package for 3.5 is renamed as pip3 to avoid conflict. (By the package manager).

The upgrade syntax for any package is

```
<script_name_for_pip> install --upgrade <package_name>
```

and the package name is **pip** in pipy. That justifies why you have to provide pip as the package name and **NOT pip3**.

- pip -v doesn't work because pip executable doesn't exist.

somewhat is a related note, you can also use the below to upgrade pip or any package for that matter.

```
easy_install-3.5 -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

[PEP 394](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) describes naming of Python binaries, and according to its recommendations, you have `pip3` in system because `pip` is reserved for Python 2.x pip.

Of course you can alias `pip` to `pip3`, but it's not recommended.